# Trouble with TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have an view, in which I have a UIScrollView. I wanted to add the first subview to it a grouped table view from another controller. So I did this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    TodayViewControllerIPhone *todayController = [[TodayViewControllerIPhone alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.firstTitle = todayController.title;
    NSLog(@"%@", todayController.title);
    todayController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:todayController.view];

    self.navBar.topItem.title = self.firstTitle;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

But I get nothing from the created class... Even it's title is null... Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you initialize `todayController.title` ? What does `TodayViewControllerIPhone` subclass?

Comment: well, I initialized it in the view controller, where scroll view is... and the TodayViewController is the UITableViewController with the grouped table view)

Comment: You will have to provide more details than that, or I doubt if anyone is going to be able to help you. Since you already refer to more than one view controller, it's hard to tell from your answer which view controller you initialized it in. Show some code with the TodayViewControllerIPhone initialization and where the title is initialized.

Comment: I found out my mistake - I was using simulator 4.3 and all the methods of the table view were in ViewWillAppear method

Answer (score -1):

You are not supposed to present two view controllers onscreen simultaneously.  It's not guaranteed to work.  Only the special container types (like UISplitViewController) can do this.  In iOS5 you are supposed to be able to write your own containers, but I couldn't find the documentation on that.

Comment: View Controller Programming Guide
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html

"Each content view controller object you create is responsible for managing all the views in a single view hierarchy. The one-to-one correspondence between a view controller and the views in its view hierarchy is the key design consideration. You should not use multiple content view controllers to manage different portions of the same view hierarchy."

Comment: Correct, one controller at a time.  Can definitely have multiple views, but one controller.